# C# Excel VSTO - Deselect all cells

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So when you open an Excel Workbook, each sheet saves the last selection of cells you made from the previous time you used the sheet.  In C#, i would like to deselect (de-focus, whatever...)  all cells in every sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always an active cell on the sheet which is active. The only thing you can do is select the least annoying cell, such as the first one.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and saved the initial state before starting the add-in (using activesheet, activecell) and just return to the saved state after I do my work.